# c function referenced by cpp class alters const variables and const variable pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, parameters, extern

I have class *cppClass* with method *cppFunction*. *cppFunction* calls c function *cFunctionA* which in turn calls *cFunctionB*.

The problem I am encountering is that upon exiting *cFunctionB* - right after the debugger passes the closing brace - in some apparent random fashion
 1. pointer variables *parameter1* and *parameter2* are set to NULL
 2. unsigned int variables *parameter1_size* and *parameter2_size* are set to 0.

This is a very strange behaviour to me, especially when you consider that the affected variables are **const input parameters to both functions** cFunctionA and cFunctionB.

Each occurance of this problem affects only some of the above mentioned variables above at a time.

I have no idea what might be causing this issue, therefore I have included as many details as possible, even tough I believe some are not relevant.

Please find below my code:

cppFunction.h

```
    extern "C" {

    unsigned int cFunctionAconst (unsigned char* parameter1, const unsigned int parameter1_size, const unsigned char* parameter2, const unsigned int parameter2_size);

    unsigned int cFunctionB(const unsigned char* parameter1, const unsigned int parameter1_size, const unsigned char* parameter2, const unsigned int parameter2_size, const int parameter3, const int parameter4);

            }


#ifndef CPP_CLASS_H
#define CPP_CLASS_H

class cppClass : public QDialog
{

Q_OBJECT

public:
     explicit cppClass();

      //some other methods

      void cppFunction(string someParameter1, string someParameter2);

};

#endif
```

cppFunction.cpp
    cppClass::cppClass():QDialog(){}

```
void cppClass::cppFunction(string someParameter1, string someParameter2)
{
    const unsigned char* parameter1;
    const unsigned char* parameter2;

    const unsigned int parameter1_size;
    const unsigned int parameter2_size;

    int functionAResult;


    //assign parameters parameter1, parameter1_size, parameter2, parameter2_size

    functionAResult=cFunctionA(parameter1, parameter1_size, parameter2, parameter2_size);
}
```

cFunctions.h

```
unsigned int cFunctionA(const unsigned char* parameter1, const unsigned int parameter1_size, const unsigned char* parameter2, const unsigned int parameter2_size)
{
    const int parameter3;
    const int parameter4;


    // do something;

    functionB(parameter1, parameter1_size, parameter2, parameter2_size, parameter3, parameter4);

    // do some other something;

}


unsigned int cFunctionB(const unsigned char* parameter1, const unsigned int parameter1_size, const unsigned char* parameter2, const unsigned int parameter2_size, const int parameter3, const int parameter3)
{

    // do something;

}
```

This is very strange to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `parameter1` to point to something in your class object, then your logic in either `cFunctionA()` or `cFunctionB()` is overstepping the length bounds and overwriting something else in the class object.

Comment: That's what I thought myself at first. However, this should not be possible as the involved parameters are "const". Also I have checked this and it is not the problem. The strange think is that the corruption of the variable happens right after the debugger leaves cFunctionB - closing brace - and before the control is handed back into cFunctionA.

Comment: `const` doesn't mean jack diddly in the real world.   If you have a pointer, particularly in the data region (as opposed to text), you can write to it and corrupt things.

Comment: The bug is the code you didn't show. You are almost certainly corrupting your stack. The corruption probably has nothing to do with the `const` pointers you are worried about.

Comment: @Ross Shultz Ok, fine about the const pointer variable, how about the const int var?

Comment: @Mark Lakata Ok I will investigate that line.